# How do I exchange two images in a webpage (on two consecutive clicks) using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two images among many that I want to swap places between. If I click on one image, then the other, the respective images should swap with each other and the rest should remain the same. I'm a beginner at this so any help or direction would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How does your html-markup look like? You provide way to few information to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach that swaps the actual elements rather than the src of the img, also avoids using external variables for the swap.

```
$('img.swap').on('click', function() {
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.hasClass('clicked')) {
        t.removeClass('clicked');
        return;
    }

    var clicked = $('img.swap.clicked')
    if (clicked.length === 0) {
        t.addClass('clicked');        
        return;
    }
    var placeHolder = $('<div id="placeholder"></div>');
    clicked.before(placeHolder);
    t.after(clicked);
    placeHolder.before(t).remove();
    clicked.removeClass('clicked');
});​
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/BxST9/3/ (using div instead of img but shouldn't make a difference)

Answer (score 2):

This works also for every image:

```
 <img src="http://stunningwebsitetemplates.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/jquery.png"/>
 <img src="http://bloggerschmidt.de/images/stories/logo-mootools.gif" />
 <img src="http://stunningwebsitetemplates.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/jquery.png"/>
 <img src="http://bloggerschmidt.de/images/stories/logo-mootools.gif" />
```

JS

```
 $(function(){
     var src="";
     var old;
     $("img").click(function(){
         if(src=="")
         {
            src=$(this).attr("src"); 
             old=$(this);
         }
         else
         {
             old.attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
             $(this).attr("src",src);
             src="";
         }
      });
 });​
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without any global variable.

html

```
<div id="images">
  <img scr="/images/1.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/2.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/3.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/4.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/5.jpg" />&nbsp;
</div>
```

Js file

```
$('img').click(function(){
    if($('#images img').hasClass('selected')){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.selected').attr('src',src);
        $(this).attr('src',$('.selected').attr('src'));
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else
        $(this).addClass('selected');   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

html

```
<div>
  <img scr="/images/1.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/2.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/3.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/4.jpg" />&nbsp;
  <img scr="/images/5.jpg" />&nbsp;
</div>
```

Js file

```
(function() {
    var swapArray = [];
    var count=0;
    $('img').click(function(){
        count++;
        swapArray.push($(this).attr('src'));
        $(this).addClass(count);
        if(count==2){
            $('.1').attr('src',swapArray[1]).removeClass('1');
            $('.2').attr('src',swapArray[0]).removeClass('2');
            swapArray.length = 0;
            count=0;
        }
    });
}());​
```

Comment: you can use global variables if you know how to use them. :)

Comment: It's not a matter of how to use them, it's just bad practice. Just use a closure.

Comment: You can not store data in local variables to use them in future.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: Christoph is right. If you do need access to them from outside code, just expose them through a single global namespace variable. At least that way, you can find some way to make it explicit (e.g. call it MY_LIB or some other conspicuously global name).

Comment: Yes, you can use a single global namespace, but still you will be using global variables. :)

Comment: @Christoph: Why don't you try yourself? Try some better approach if you have and share with us.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: correction: a *single* global variable that can easily be identified as such. How many global variable do you think jQuery uses? Two: `jQuery` and `$`, and the second one is purely for convenience and can be disabled.

Comment: @PPvG: Why don't you provide a better solution.

Comment: @Sac: Please try any solution and let us know if helps you.

Comment: @PPvG & Christoph: I have added one more solution without using any global variable.

Answer (score 0):

See the example on: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvp4j/1/

```
var selected;
$("img").click(
    function() { 
        if (!selected)
        {
            selected = this; 
            $(selected).addClass("selected");
        }
        else
        {
            var src1 = $(selected).attr("src");
            var src2 = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).attr("src", src1);
            $(selected).attr("src", src2);
            $(selected).removeClass("selected");
            selected = null;
        }
    }
);
```

My code adds also a `selected` class so you can highlight the clicked image...

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML:

```
<img src="image_1.jpg" />
<img src="image_2.jpg" />
<img src="image_3.jpg" />
<img src="image_4.jpg" />
```

You could use the following JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var previous = null;

    $('img').click(function() {
        var current = $(this);
        if (current.is(previous)) {    // clicked same image twice; reset
            reset_clicked();
        } else if (previous != null) { // two images clicked; swap
            swap_src(previous, current);
            reset_clicked();
        } else {
            set_clicked(current);
        }
    });

    function reset_clicked() {
        previous.removeClass('clicked');
        previous = null;
    }

    function set_clicked(img) {
        img.addClass('clicked');
        previous = img;
    }

    function swap_src(img1, img2) {
        var src1 = img1.attr('src');
        img1.attr('src', img2.attr('src'));
        img2.attr('src', src1);
    }
}());​
```

The `'clicked'` class is added purely so you can use CSS to style clicked images. This class could also be used to identify any previously-clicked images, but I've used a JavaScript variable instead because that's quicker than a DOM lookup.

There's a demo on JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/cvthL/2](http://jsfiddle.net/cvthL/2/)

*This answer was posted as an improved version of [Jitendra Pancholi's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11862292/990877) and an alternative to his/her [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11862771/990877).*

Comment: See my 2nd answer which is very much simple than this :)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi I did see it, and it's very nice. I deliberately chose a more complicated approach (including a cancellable first click) to show how your first answer could have been done without global variables. Notice the closure around the code? No global variables. At all. Neat, huh? :)

Comment: you have also taken one global variable "clicked_image".

Comment: @JitendraPancholi No, `clicked_image` is in the anonymous function's scope (inside the closure); it's not set to `window.clicked_image` like in your first answer. That was the whole point of posting this answer...

Comment: Yeah, yes, you can put my first solution inside a closure as i updated already :)

Comment: Yes its very simple. But still i would like to tell you that you can use global variables if you know how to handle them. And the main thing was not closure but the approach to achieve the desired output efficiently (as i mentioned in my 2nd solution). :)

Comment: Its not bad to vote-up an answer which you see efficient and good :-)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: It's still bad practice. In time, you **will** forget that you set a global `var count`. And you will write another script that also uses a global `var count`. And you will pull out your hair trying to find what the heck is going wrong with your new script. Trust me. I've been there.

Comment: hahahaha.....I am laughing a lot on you... I can't see any global variable in my 2nd solution but you have seen it. :P I think you are very much busy in scratching your head that how can anyone else provide a better approach than you. Face the reality and try to improve yourself. We people are here to help :)

Comment: Check your comment dude and see your language. See yourself then comment on anyone. got it.

Comment: And count is in the anonymous function's scope (inside the closure).

Comment: @JitendraPancholi My comment was in response to your comment (*"But still i would like to tell you that you can use global variables if you know how to handle them"*). If you want your site or application to be maintainable, you're better off avoiding global variables. Because **if** you use global var with a common name (like "count") and you forget about it (do you remember all the code you wrote last year, or the year before that?) then you are likely to run into strange and hard-to-debug errors. I was just giving friendly advice. Again: what is your problem?

Comment: oh dear still you are not getting me. First of all i don't know anything about Sac's application and second thing we should never copy and paste the exact solution that we get here. We always choose variable names according to application standards. We only provide approach here, we never recommend anyone to copy and paste the exact code. I am not able to understand your problem.

Comment: And if you are talking about common variable names then kindly review your code, you have also taken a common name (clicked_image) which anyone can you use in many places for different use.

Comment: And if i already provided a better approach in second solution then why are you stuck in my first solution? This simply proves my previous comment on you.

Comment: And taken care of your friendly advice i had modified my first answer. :)

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: `clicked_image` **isn't global**. All this started because Chrisoph suggested that "*global vars should be avoided*". Yes, you've fixed your code; no more global vars. But in your comments you still stubbornly maintain that global vars are fine "if you know how to handle them". If you won't take it from us, [take it from JavaScript guru Douglas Crockford](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/).

Comment: You are very stubborn i see :) dear its not compulsory not to use global variables. After yous suggestion i modified my code(also provided second solution) and not using global variables. Those two variables are in scope of anonymous function, those are not global. Kindly have a glass of cold water and see it again :) Its my friendly advice to you.